# Android alert dialog with OnClickListener - Syntax Error

Tags: android

I am having trouble with an Android alert dialog. I want to finish the activity when the OK button is tapped. I have added a listener event as below, but I can't seem to get it to be syntactically correct.

I *think* I have got all the braces and brackets closed in the right places but the compiler gives me:

; Expected

} Expected

) Expected

For the "new DialogInterface.OnClickListner() {" line.

Just wondering if anyone could point out where this is going wrong?

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .SetMessage("Message!")
                    .SetTitle("Queued")
                    .SetPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Finish activity
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                   .Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way to achieve this in the end was changing the code to be:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                     .SetMessage("Message!")
                     .SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) =>
                     {
                         Finish();
                     })
                     .SetTitle("Test")
                     .Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

> });
>
> .Show();

with this:

> }).Show();

Comment: No dice, it highlights the same line and complains about  } ) ; being expected.

This works fine:

 .SetPositiveButton("OK", (Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener)null)

It only seems to break when I add code to the listener.. :/